# 'tags' attribute of a property function

Tags: python, scripting

It looks like that since Blender 2.80 all property functions in module `bpy.props` has an extra argument `tags`.

Documentations says

> Enumerator of tags that are defined by parent class.

I don't understand which values this attribute expects and how this argument should impact on a property.

I was trying to find something in release notes of 2.8 version and didn't find any hints on this matter.

Comment: Do you know of an ID type can set this for... most throw `TypeError: FloatProperty(): property-tags not available for 'Object'`

Comment: Yes but: ```>>> D.meshes[0].polygons[0].test
(<built-in function IntProperty>, {'tags': {'TEST'}})```   
          
```>>> D.meshes[0].polygons[0].test = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MeshPolygon' object attribute 'test' is read-only```

Comment: First comment result of `bpy.types.Object.foo = FloatProperty(tags=set())`  whereas you are trying to set it to the Face via `bpy;types.Polygon.foo` which **wont work** because to work  the `bpy.props.Foo`  method  requires the type to be a subclass of `bpy.types.ID` or a bone. Properties on non ID types display the error as shown in comment.  You are simply monkey patching it onto the type, it is not being wired up as a property akin to `bpy.types.Foo.xxx = property(setter, getter)`

Comment: Looks like no one ID type can get a property with `tags` attribute. No sure that this knowledge is make us closer to understanding purpose of the attribute.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect a dead question, but did you ever find the answer to this? I've wondered about it for a while, and like you, I couldn't find anything about it...

Comment: @StrikeDigital No, I guess someone who is able to read C++ have to have a look at the source code to shed light on this.